# React importing/exporting issues?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Please let me know what I'm missing so that I could render these files on the screen. My goal is to show the 'Teachers List' data on the screen. But I keep getting an error code that it can't be found. I keep getting this error code: **

```
Error Code:

Failed to compile.

src/Teachers.js
  Line 5:18:  'TeacherList' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I'm having issues posting this question because stack overflow keeps saying "it looks like your post is mostly code." So I'm adding more details here as a filler.

---

(Teachers.js file)

```
import React from 'react';
import TeacherList from '../data/teachers';

const Teachers = () => {
  let teachers = TeacherList.map((teacher) => {
    return (
      <li className="teacher" key={teacher.id} >
        <img className="teacher-img" src={teacher.img_src} alt="teacher" />
        <h3>{teacher.name}</h3>
        <p>{teacher.bio}</p>
      </li>
    );
  }); 
  
  return (
    <div className="main-content">
      <h2>Teachers</h2>
      <ul className="group">
        {teachers}    
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Teachers;
```

---

(teachers.js file)

```
export const TeacherList = [
  {
    name: "Angie McAngular",
    bio: "Angie is a web developer and teacher who is passionate about building scalable, data driven web apps, especially ones that address old problems with new tech!",
    img_src: "http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap-4/img/angie.png",
    id: "teach-1"
  },
  {
    name: "NodeStradamus",
    bio: "'NodeStra' is a software engineer and philosopher trying to leave the world better than he found it. He codes for non-profits, eCommerce, and large-scale web apps.",
    img_src: "http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap-4/img/nodestradamus.png",
    id: "teach-2"
  },
  {
    name: "Geo 'Lo' Cation",
    bio: "Geo is a JavaScript developer working on large-scale applications. He's also a teacher who strives to support students in removing all barriers to learning code.",
    img_src: "http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap-4/img/geo.png",
    id: "teach-3"
  },
  {
    name: "Ecma Scriptnstuff",
    bio: "Ecma found her passion for computers and programming over 15 years ago. She is excited to introduce people to the wonderful world of JavaScript.",
    img_src: "http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap-4/img/ecma.png",
    id: "teach-4"
  },
  {
    name: "Jay Query",
    bio: "Jay is a developer, author of CSS: The Missing Manual, JavaScript & jQuery: The Missing Manual, and web development teacher.",
    img_src: "http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap-4/img/jay.png",
    id: "teach-5"
  },
  {
    name: "Json Babel",
    bio: "All of his professional life, Json has worked with computers online; he is a polyglot programmer and likes using the right tools for the job.",
    img_src: "http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap-4/img/json.png",
    id: "teach-6"
  }
];

export default TeacherList;
```

---

(App.js file)

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Teachers from './Teachers.js';
import Header from './Header';
import Courses from './Courses';

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" render= { () => <About title='About' />} />
      <Route path="/teachers" component={Teachers} />
      <Route path="/courses" component={Courses} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure the `teachers.js` file is in the `../data` dir? Because it looks like this should compile correctly. Looking at it the `data` dir should be on the same level as the `src` dir.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do named import as `TeacherList` is not exported by default.

```
import { TeacherList } from 'from your path'
```

Answer (score 0):

in teacher.js i think there is no need to have default and named export both at the same time . So i request you to remove named export and use only default export .

eg: const teacherList = [];

export default teacherList;

Answer (score 0):

I ran your project.
Ensure this structure is kept.

- data

  - teachers.js
- src

  - Teachers.js
  - App.js

Should work fine.

[image]